# Can't get referenced entity properties anytime, only in rendering method

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

```
/** @ODM\Document(collection="Entities") */
class Entity extends Document {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $_id;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="\Doctrine\Documents\Entities\Entity2", simple=true) */
    protected $entity2;
}

/** @ODM\Document(collection="Entities2") */
class Entity2 extends Document {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $_id;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $label;
}
```

My problem is when I call referenced entity `$entity->getEntity2()` it returns the `entity2` but with `public $__isInitialized__ => bool(false)`. Then when I try to call `$entity->getEntity2()->getId()` it throws `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentNotFoundException The "Proxies\__CG__\Doctrine\Documents\Entities\Entity2" document with identifier "54de5341642c8769150041a7" could not be found.`

Weird is that this happen when I call it before rendering in my framework. When I do the same during rendering method it works but it doesn't work for example in form submit-handling methods...

*I have cleaned cache, proxies and hydrators. The document with this `ObjectID` is in my database and it gets returned, only not initialized and can't get any of its properties except in the rendering method*

This is returned by calling `getEntity2()` (mind `$__isInititalized = false`)

> class Proxies__CG__\Doctrine\Documents\Entities\Entity2#178 (6) {
>   public $**initializer** => class Closure#160 (3) { public $static =>
>   array(2) { 'documentPersister' => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister#166 (11) { ... }
>   'reflectionId' => class ReflectionProperty#165 (2) { ... } } public
>   $this => class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Proxy\ProxyFactory#78 (7) {
>   private $metadataFactory => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory#74 (9) { ... }
>   private $uow => class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\UnitOfWork#76 (23) { ... }
>   private $proxyNamespace => string(7) "Proxies" private $proxyGenerator
>   => class Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator#79 (4) { ... } private $autoGenerate => int(1) private $definitions => array(1) { ... }
>   private $metadataFactory => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory#74 (9) { ... } }
>   public $parameter => array(1) { '$proxy' => string(10) "" } } public
>   $**cloner** => class Closure#170 (3) { public $static => array(3) {
>   'documentPersister' => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister#166 (11) { ... }
>   'classMetadata' => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata#155 (38) { ... }
>   'reflectionId' => class ReflectionProperty#165 (2) { ... } } public
>   $this => class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Proxy\ProxyFactory#78 (7) {
>   private $metadataFactory => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory#74 (9) { ... }
>   private $uow => class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\UnitOfWork#76 (23) { ... }
>   private $proxyNamespace => string(7) "Proxies" private $proxyGenerator
>   => class Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator#79 (4) { ... } private $autoGenerate => int(1) private $definitions => array(1) { ... }
>   private $metadataFactory => class
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory#74 (9) { ... } }
>   public $parameter => array(1) { '$proxy' => string(10) "" } } public
>   $**isInitialized** => bool(false) protected $_id => NULL protected
>   $label => NULL protected $id => string(24) "54de5341642c8769150041a7"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may cause the use of "simple=true"

> Simple references reduce the amount of storage used, both for the document itself and any indexes on the reference field; however, simple references cannot be used with discriminators, since there is no DBRef object in which to store a discriminator value.

look [documetation](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/reference-mapping.html#simple-references)

Comment: There's no problem with other entities with `simple=true` I found out... IMO it's just a bug but I haven't found a cause of it...